# GitHub: Change commit author name and email in closed PR

Tags: git, github

I made a fork, created new branch, made a commit and submitted a PR to the original repo.
Then, deleted a forked repo and closed a PR without merging.

Can I somehow change user name and email of the commit in that closed PR? The original repo is maintained by me.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I contacted GitHub Support and they deleted the PR.